# redux-thunk and user interaction

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have dozens of instances where asynchronous API requests are triggered with Redux Thunk middleware, like so:

```
const someHandler = async () => {
    const result = await dispatch(someAsyncApiCallActionCreator());
    // ... do something with the result
}
```

I need to change the behavior to display a component first and wait for user interaction (button click) before the actual call is made, while keeping the initial dispatch as shown above intact.

The display part is easy, I can toggle a property in the state first in my action creator:

```
const someAsyncApiCallActionCreator = params => dispatch => {
    // Trigger property state change first in this action:
    dispatch(showMyComponent());
    // Proceed
    return fetch(...);
}
```

However, I can't wrap my head around how I could delay the following fetch call until e.g. a button was pressed in a component.

It could work if I store a promise in the state and then select and resolve this in the component, but as no non-serializable data should be stored in the state, this doesn't seem like a good approach.

Is there any other possible way, while keeping the initial call from above intact and without changing dozens of invocations?

Answer (score 0):

In general it's considered to be a better practice to keep UI state, such as whether a component is shown, in a local component state rather than in redux.  So you would want to avoid this `dispatch(showMyComponent())`.

It's also a bad practice to return state from a dispatch.  The dispatch should deal with fetching the value and setting it in the state.  Retrieval should be done with a selector.  The selector will return null/undefined/etc. on the first call because the data hasn't been loaded yet, but `connect()` or `useSelector` will subscribe to changes and retrieve the updated value once it has been loaded by the action that you called.

As far as executing the fetch, just don't call `someHandler` until the button is clicked.

Here's an example setup, where we switch between showing the button and the data based on whether the data is loaded.  You can also add a third option to display when the button has been clicked but the data not yet loaded, and a fourth option for when there is an error fetching the data, etc.  This is just a starting point.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {

  // data will be undefined until it is exists in the state
  const data = useSelector(someSelector);

  const isLoaded = data !== undefined;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const someHandler = () => {
    // don't await any return.  just dispatch
    dispatch(someAsyncApiCallActionCreator(props.param))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoaded ? 
        <LoadedComponent data={data}/>
        :
        <button onClick={() => someHandler()}>Load Data</button>
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```